# send notification to android device from server without GCM(Google Cloud Messaging)

Tags: php, android, notifications, push-notification

I have to send notification from server to android device. I developed application which got notification from server by using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). But as I already have server then why to use GCM. I am not getting the purpose of using GCM. Can we send notification from server to android application without using GCM.

Answer (score 1):

General Communication Pattern :

Device --> HTTPRequest -- >Server , Server -->HTTPResponse --> Device

But in this case, the device gets a response only when you send a request from your device to the server. Hence, whenever you need something new from your server you need to make a 
request.

Using GCM, you do not need to make this request explicitly to your server. You'll automatically be notified when something new happens (depending on your implementation).

Comment: its works like Client-server architecture. I want to implement server t-client architecture.

Comment: Server client is done using GCM since you need reverse communication. There are other libraries too such as Parse which are easier to implement. https://parse.com/docs/android_guide

Answer (score 0):

You are having server but GCM is totally different thing then your server.

GCM will monitor Your Application server that any changes made or not ??

And if anything created then it will send you notification without refresh or reload the Application.

and **GCM will send you notification when your application is not working as well**

Comment: Weather GCM store that notificationor message on their server?

Comment: Yes, GCM(Google Colud Messaging) will store notification message

Comment: Till then it release all messages to you.

Comment: Can We check all history of that stored notification ?

Comment: for that you need to store that notification at your database server